# Check previous records to update current record in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to check  Previous records in order to see if the current record should be updated.

Don't want to use the lag function because I will not have the information on how many records to go back.

I have a table that contains Employee Raise information. I want to Put a X in the IND field if there has been a previous Merit increase PCT greater than the current Merit increase within the last 6 months. The current Record is the 2012/05 record.

```
Emp    Action   Date       Code     proj   PCT   Ind
====================================================
123    raise    2012/01    COL      acct   2
123    raise    2012/01    Merit    soft   7
123    raise    2012/02    Merit    Acct   4
123    Raise    2012/05    merit    soft   6     ?
```

Comment: :Can you please give a better explanation with example.

Comment: Sure, I am running a query on the EmployeeRecords Table(Like above) that I would like to see an X in the IND column  if there has been a  Merit raise PCT for the employee that is greater than the current record PCT raise in the last 6 month. The record for date 2012/05 that has 6pct would get a x in ind column because there is a previous Merit/Raise record for that Employee on 2012/01 of 7. Sorry was not clear that this is just a query and all records need to be returned in the query just with IND field X if there was a previous Higher PCT raise in the last 6 Months.

Comment: :Thanks Ovile how can you identify the previous Merit/Raise record .On what columns i mean ...is it `emp and proj`?

Comment: It would be EMP and Code..Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly efficient but you can use a brute force approach

```
UPDATE <<table_name>> a
   SET ind = 'X'
 WHERE <<date column>> = (SELECT MAX(<<date column>>
                            FROM <<table name>> b
                           WHERE a.emp = b.emp)
   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM <<table name>> c
                WHERE a.emp = c.emp
                  AND c.code = 'Merit'
                  AND c.action = 'raise'
                  AND c.pct  > a.pct
                  AND c.<<date column>> > sysdate - interval '6' month 
                  AND c.rowid != a.rowid);
```

Comment: :Wow +1 for the solution ,can this be done with analytical functions?

Comment: Wow is Right! and thanks! I looked at lag functions but i could not see a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a query rather than an update, this might work

```
Select 
  emp, 
  action, 
  date, 
  code, 
  project, 
  pct,
  case when max(case when code='Merit' and action='raise' then pct end)
    over (partition by emp order by date 
      range between interval '6' month preceding and current row
    ) > pct then 'X' end as ind
From the_table
```

I don't have a database to test this against right now so I'm not entirely sure this will work but think it should. **Edit**: worked out how to get SQL Fiddle going on my iPad. This seems to work, however it will put an X in all the rows that meet the condition and not just the most recent.

Comment: What was the trouble you had with sql fiddle on your iPad?  (sqlfiddle is my site, so I'd like to fix it if possible).

Comment: @jake I couldn't work out how to choose Oracle as the database the first time I looked, holding it in portrait. Took me a while to see the button on the top right rather than the usual drop-down, since the UI is slightly different from landscape or computer. Partly I also didn't fancy typing complex SQL in using the iPad keyboard. I did find that I couldn't get copy and paste to work and positioning the cursor is a little tricky. Neither is a major problem though. I really appreciate SQL fiddle. So simple and so effective!

Comment: @MikeMeyers I did know about the copy/paste issue; that's a bug with codemirror (I'm hoping they'll fix that soon).  The landscape/portrait UI changes do take a bit of getting used to - it's a standard bootstrap convention.  My main goal with sqlfiddle on iOS was to have it be usable to read fiddles rather than to write them, to be honest, for the reason you point out - typing out complex SQL in that environment is not fun.